# Machine learning for symbolic mathematics

Tags: machine-learning, reference-request

I  came across [a meaningful article](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1912.01412.pdf?fbclid=IwAR0Dbz9D9HmuCr1qSZB3xMh86vRTi4B8WNEXLr5w_DTA8RwX8U4n_uF4PWg) about the use of machine learning (in particular, with Mathematica) to solve ODEs and find undefined integrals. Are there any other works, especially done with Mathematica, on this topic ? I would be thankful to colleagues for exact and available references.

PS. [The resent article](https://www.mathnet.ru/php/archive.phtml?wshow=paper&jrnid=tmf&paperid=10418&option_lang=eng) is not accessible by me.

Comment: When in doubt check arXiv.org. The paper you mention is at https://arxiv.org/abs/2204.11613

Comment: @1729taxi: Many thanks from me to you for the reference.

Comment: Might want to do a search on the topic "symbolic regression". Include Mathematica in the terms if you want results using that software.

Comment: Can you elaborate your comment, indicating the connection with machine learning for symbolic math? TIA.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau: Thank you for your interest to the question. [Here](https://www.google.com.ua/search?q=symbolic+regression+mathematica&ei=OucAZNHXKJHr7_UP8recgAg&ved=0ahUKEwjR3JvC7L39AhWR9bsIHfIbB4AQ4dUDCA8&uact=5&oq=symbolic+regression+mathematica&gs_lcp=Cgxnd3Mtd2l6LXNlcnAQAzIJCAAQDRCABBATOgkIABAeEA0QsAM6BQgAEIAEOgYIABAWEB46BwgAEIAEEBM6CAgAEBYQHhATOgsIABAWEB4Q8QQQEzoKCAAQFhAeEA8QE0oECEEYAUoFCEASATFQwwZY30tgmFFoAXAAeACAAZUDiAHKDpIBCTEuOS4xLjAuMZgBAKABAcgBAcABAQ&sclient=gws-wiz-serp) are the results of the search. As I understand it, this is similar to `FindFormula`.

Comment: [Here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1912.05752) is a review of of Lample and Charton, 2019.